# Post tweets through Objective-c Using STTwitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, xcode5

So here is my problem. I am trying to authenticate an app and post a tweet on the twitter using STTwitter API for iOS. Here is my code using STTwitter framework.

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter= [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerName:@"mytwitterdisplayname" 
                 consumerKey:@"consumerkey"
                 consumerSecret:@"consumersecret" 
                 username:@"myloginuseremailid" 
                 password:@"password"];
```

And using this object twitter as follows

```
           [twitter postStatusUpdate:@"test" inReplyToStatusID:nil
                     latitude:nil
                     longitude:nil
                     placeID:nil
                     displayCoordinates:nil
                     trimUser:nil
           successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
                     // ...
          } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                     // ...
             }];
```

However, each time I run this code I get following error as authentication failure.

```
"Error Domain=STHTTPRequest Code=220 "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource." UserInfo=0xdf46550 {NSLocalizedDescription=Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.}"
```

Is there something wrong I am doing? Any help is much appreciated.
I am using iOs7 and Xcode 5.0.2

Comment: ...are you actually using oauth credentials that have permissions to post on the user's behalf?

Comment: Right now I am not using oauth credentials. But Twitter docs indicate 
I need to. So I just put a request for x-oauth verified tokens on their developer portal.

Comment: Don't forget to call the [verifyCredentials](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#verify-the-credentials) method before posting the status.

Comment: YOU got the solution please inform me...or share the code ....@Jayesh